# Custom "Panels" User Dashboard not showing

Tags: panels

I cannot for the life of me work out why my custom Panels user dashboard are not showing once a user (Role) has logged-in. Instead of showing the relevant Panel Variation based on the said User Role, post-login simply shows the main Profile tabs irrespective of whether I'm Admin or any other 'Test' role user (there are 5 different Roles, so a different Panel Variation for each Role).
The Role Criteria is set in the Panel Variation and a Rule tell the system which Pane to show. I've also tried this with a Homebox model and still get the same Main Profile tabs showing; I don't know why or what influences the Tabs to show and cannot find any tutuorials online to explain why or if it's something I'm doing wrong or its 'bug'.

To recap, I'd like to ensure that a Users Dashboard (D/B) IS THE MAIN page show when the user has logged in (ala Drupal.org user home D/B).

Would anyone like to shed some light on the generalisation of acheiving what must be a simple workflow task?

Comment: Is the first variation?  The first variation that matches the criteria will be shown, so if you have another variation placed before the one you want to show, and that variation matches too, users will see the first variation rather than the one you want to show.

Comment: Cheers Patrick, For now I'm simply using the "User Template" supplied with Panels, edited and cloned 4 more Variants for each of the 4 User types. Each should show, dependent on the Selection rule: "This panel will be selected if Logged in user has role: xxxx".At the moment none of them show. I've called the Panel "user_view" and that is the Panel I presume should show (of course the Selected Role Variant will kick in based on the Login Rule). For now, I've manually set 'test' user Roles at the back end so I can test. Using Ubercart for subscriptions to manage both free/paid entry etc.

Comment: Correction. The Panel IS now showing based on the User role specified in the Panel Variant. The problem however, is that the Menu Tabs from the "My Account" link is also showing from the URL: mysite/user. It is now them I wish not to show as I'm using a custom link in the Panel to a custom block to link to those components. Sorry for the digress now on my original question. (-:

Comment: Are the menu tabs being displayed in Panels?  If not, this is a theming issue, not a Panels issue....

Comment: One of the issues in my custom Panel was that "Let the system choose" under the Panel Template option, so I disabled all those options across my 4 Panel Variants. Also, in my primary Panel Variant, a included Content referred to a Main Profile, so thta was showing data. But after trying the Corrola Theme and back to my 'working' Bartik 7.0, I will for now conclude that it is Bartik. I will close this issue andmark it as 'resolved' I'll come back once I have solved it my way. Thanks again for the help.